# Alternate way to "<rewrite>" web.config. How to accomplish it programatically. WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have the following two rules for my WCF:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Rewrite requests to /MyService to /MyService.svc -->
        <rule name="MyService" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="MyService/(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyService.svc/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <!-- Remove path /MoreServices from url -->
        <rule name="example" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*(MoreServices)(.+)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

The first rule:

```
<!-- Rewrite requests to /MyService to /MyService.svc -->

<rule name="MyService" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="MyService/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyService.svc/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Rewrites calls that get sent without the svc extension to the svc service.

The second rule:

```
<!-- Remove path /MoreServices from url -->
<rule name="example" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*(MoreServices)(.+)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Removes an extra path and directs to the correct service.

Everything works fine, however, the site I will be publishing to does not allow the `<rule>` tag to be used in the web.config.  My question is, how can I modify my WCF to accomplish the two rules above programmatically.  Basically duplicating the logic of the two items mentioned above in C# as part of the WCF service.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Very easy to fix, first remove the entire `<rewrite>` section from your web.config.  Then just add new file (type global.asax) to your project if you do not already have it.

Add the following code in the Application_BeginRequest method:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Raw URL
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string rawUrl = context.Request.RawUrl;

        // Extra Path to be removed
        const string EXTRA_PATH = "/MoreServices";

        // Rewrite requests to /MyService to /MyService.svc
        if (!rawUrl.Contains(".svc"))
        {
            // Index of last forward slash
            int idxLastSlash = rawUrl.LastIndexOf('/');
            // Insert .svc before last slash
            rawUrl = rawUrl.Insert(idxLastSlash, ".svc");              
        }

        // Remove extra path EXTRA_PATH from url
        if (rawUrl.Contains(EXTRA_PATH))
        {
            // Remove extra path
            rawUrl = rawUrl.Replace(EXTRA_PATH, "");
        }

        // Rewrite Path if it has been modified
        if (rawUrl != context.Request.RawUrl)
        {
            // Note: Added "~" to avoid error: "The virtual path XX maps to another application, which is not allowed."
            context.RewritePath("~" + rawUrl, false);
        }

    }
```

This will work the same way as the two rules above in the web.config. Hope this will help someone.